# Why can't I store the return value of a shell function by variable assignment?

Tags: bash, shell

```
function double {
    read -p "Enter the value: " value
    return $(($value * 2))
}

result=$(double)

echo "The new result is $result."
```

When I run this piece of code the `echo` command doesn't print the computed value, but when I changed `result=$(double)` to `double; result=$?` it worked. Why can't I just assign the return value directly?

Comment: The result of a command substitution like `$(double)` is the standard output of the command, NOT its exit status (which is what `return` sets).  Using `echo` instead of `return` would be one solution (and would allow you to produce results outside of the 8-bit range supported by status codes).

Comment: A shell function, despite of its name, does not have a _return value_  (shell functions are more like _subroutines_ in other languages). Therefore there isn't anything you can assign.  A function can set an exit code on return, and this is something you can assign (but the cases where you want to do it, are rare). I think you need to describe more in detail, what exactly you want to achieve.